# Is there any problem with the usage of static variables in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, variables, static

Is there any problem with the usage of static variable in Objective-C? If yes, please explain.

**Reason for usage of static variable**

I have two classes

1. MainView
2. WifiConnection

When the application loads, I am in the MainView class and will call a method from the `WifiConnection class(method name:send).send` method to initialize instream and outstream which is declared in the WiFiConnection class.

So it will send data successfully the first time. But sending the second time I do not need to initialize instream and outstream which is already initialized.

But this time when I look instream and outstream value it will be null. So I declared these variables as static and solved the above problem.

And also, how do I declare a class type variable as global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need only a single instance of the class, you can take a look at [Singletons](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32). They are based of static variables. This will involve some minor modification to your code and you can call functions on instances like `[[MainView sharedMainView] showMessage]`.

This is the best approach of using static variables.